# failed to open stream and permission denied errors

Tags: php

I've been stuck on two problems and I think they are related. The first is that I'm trying to upload a file (and I intend to rename after I get this to work). The second is I'm trying to log certain events.

The code to the first issue is:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], 
basename($_FILES['logo']['name']));
```

The error I get is:

```
Warning:  move_uploaded_file(224537_10150405406507786_833667785_10758194_3953892_n.jpg): 
failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/MVP/test/uploadFile.php 
on line 3 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpuDHoo6' 
to '224537_10150405406507786_833667785_10758194_3953892_n.jpg' 
in /var/www/html/MVP/test/uploadFile.php on line 3
```

The second code to the second problem looks like this:

```
function logToFile($msg){
  $logfile=dirname(__FILE__)."/../../shared/log/logCleanups.log";
  $fd = fopen($logfile, "a+");
  fwrite($fd, date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time("now")).$msg."/n");
  fclose($fd);
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/MVP/administrative/controllers/../../shared/log/logCleanups.log): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
in /var/www/html/MVP/administrative/controllers/cleanupAds.php 
on line 10 
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
in /var/www/html/MVP/administrative/controllers/cleanupAds.php on line 12
```

Oh. And, I already did the chmod 777 thing. It seems like every answer I've found is that.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem : You do not have permission to write a file to the current directory.
there are 2 ways to resolve this issue, 
 a) one by changing the destination permission to write a file.
 b) second by changing the file destination path itself,  where you have the write permission to copy/upload the file.

And for the second problem: The given path may be wrong.

Use the absolute path (Full path instead of ../../) and also check the file permission of the log file.

Answer (score 0):

The first error message is simply stating that the identity that your PHP is running under does not have permission to write the file to the directory you're attempting to write to.  Try changing your directory permissions or the identity that PHP is executing under.

The second error in your post is two separate errors (#2 and #3).  The second states that the file you're trying to open doesn't exist.  The third occurs because of the second error.

To resolve these issues, look carefully at your directory and file structures and make sure the file paths you are using are valid and accessible.

Comment: Thank you! Errors #2 & #3 don't seem to be an issue anymore. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get error 1 under control. I've got more important things to be worried about than that, so I'll put that on the back burner for now

Answer (score 0):

On the first error, it says `Permission denied`. This is fairly clear to me. You don't have permission to move files around in that directory. You'll have to change the permissions.

On the second error, you seem to be using a relative path. From what I can tell, this isn't working. Try using the full path instead of `/../../`. This may solve your `fclose()` error.